# how to repent after cursing one of your parents

Tags: parents

today I made mistake by cursing my dad and saying harsh words. I definitely know how bad the situation is. but he is a bad dad and has abandoned 7 kids including me. I've been filling his place since I was 14. I'm done and tired. said some word that I shouldn't have said. can Allah forgive me or do I keep asking my dad for forgiveness.